# Array of arrays to anonymous type and rename properties

Tags: c#, arrays, anonymous-types

I have a class

```
public class MyClass  
{  
    public string Name {get; set;}  
    public string Id {get; set;}  
}
```

I have a property in another class

```
public class AnotherClass
{  
    public MyClass[][] MyClassArray {get; set;} 
}
```

I want to create an anonymous object from the `MyClassArray` property and rename the `MyClass` properties.

For a single array of `MyClass` objects I did this

```
MyClass[] myClassArray = ...
var anonymousArray = myClassArray.Select(a => new { newName = a.Name, newId = a.Id });
```

**EDIT**

I have it working now thanks to Tim Schmelter

```
anotherClassObject.MyClassArray.Select(a => a.Select( b => new { id = b.Id, name = b.Name}))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want an array of an array of this anonymous type?

```
var ac = new AnotherClass();
// initialization ...
var anonymousArrays = ac.MyClassArray
    .Select(ar => ar.Select(a => new { newName = a.Name, newId = a.Id })
                    .ToArray())
    .ToArray();

foreach (var arr in anonymousArrays)
foreach (var x in arr)
    Console.WriteLine("Name:{0} Id:{1}", x.newName, x.newId);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. The Select(x => x.Select was what I needed.